# How do I access the property of a widget

Tags: php, yii, properties, widget

I'm new to the Yii framework and I'm trying to access a property of the of a widget let's say CMenu where I want to change the values of some public properties like activeCssClass, firstItemCssClass, lastItemCssClass, htmlOptions etc. so how do you change the property of a widget in Yii.

Details:
I'm using Yii version 1.1.12 (Aug 19, 2012) and I'm trying to generate a multilevel menu but I need to change the values of some public class parameters and I don't know how?

Answer (score 2):

Well, normally you apply needed values when you call the widget. You set them at the appropriate array inside widget call after widget class name.

```php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',
    array(
        'items' => $items,
        'id' => 'main_menu',
        'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'nav'),
        'activeCssClass' => 'active',
        'firstItemCssClass' => 'first_item'
    )
);
```

BUT! If you want to apply the values after you created some widget, but have not rendered it yet (really rare case) you can do this thing:

```php
$widget = $this->beginWidget('application.components.MyOwnWidget');
$widget->public_property = 'aaa';
$widget->renderSomething();
$this->endWidget();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on the previous answer, in case you missed it, don't forget to check the short and simple [official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view#widget) on this.