# How to access a widget view variable from a file in views directory in Yii?

Tags: php, variables, yii, yii-components

Say, I have a variable $counter defined in a widget view file. I want to access it in a views/ControllerName/actionname.php file. How do I access it?

Comment: You have to review architecture if you need such a trick.

Comment: I think this link is useful for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574084/yii-how-do-i-access-the-property-of-a-widget